# Add js function to iframe - dojo

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo

We create an iFrame like

```
var iframe = dojo.io.iframe.create(generatedRequestId);
```

We'd like to have insert an additional javascript function like

function printThis() {
window.print();
}

in the iFrame so that in the parent window we can call the printThis() function from some code like

```
_setPrintExportCookieInterval: function(/**String*/requestId, /**function*/closePopup, /**String*/exportTypeId) {
    //have the interval autoexpire after some amount of seconds
    var count = 0;
    var intervalMs = 2000;

    var intervalId = self.setInterval(function() {
        var reportCookie = dojo.cookie(requestId);
        if(reportCookie || count > 300000) { //5 mins
            //if there's a status failure, don't close the window
            if(reportCookie == "success") {
                //console.debug(exportTypeId);
                if(exportTypeId == PRINT) {
                    var iframe = dojo.byId(requestId);
                    iframe.printThis();
                }
                closePopup();
            } else {
                console.debug("print/export request returned with nonstandard status " + reportCookie);
            }
            window.clearInterval(intervalId);
            //delete the cookie
            dojo.cookie(requestId, null, {path: "/", expires: -1});
            //destroy the iframe
            //dojo.destroy(dojo.byId(requestId));
        };
        count+=intervalMs;
    }, intervalMs);

    return intervalId;
},
```

-is this possible?  I know that dojo.io.iframe.create(generatedRequestId) takes a second param that would be code that would be executed onLoad - but not necessarily a function that can be called after iframe loads?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a "global" variable or function in browser JavaScript, the variable is available as a property of the `window` object. If the iframe is from the same origin, then you have access to its `window` object through the contentWindow property of the iframe.

```
iframe.contentWindow.printThis();
```